# How to show indoor navigation path with the help of beacons using Unity and ARkit?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ibeacon, arkit, indoor-positioning-system

I am using beacons to show an indoor path using Unity Augmented Reality feature.I have bought a plugin from asset store.From beacons I am getting the RSSI(strength).I am using only a single beacon.I could pop up a message or model when inside the range.

1)How to show the direction from device to where the beacon is situated?Should I use triangulation method(Deep knowledge in maths required?)?How to achieve it?

2)Is there any alternate method other than using beacons.I think it is the future without using beacons. Blippar is already working on it(2019).

```
BluetoothLEHardwareInterface.ScanForPeripheralsWithServices(null, null, (address, name, rssi, bytes) =>
            {


                    BluetoothLEHardwareInterface.Log("item scanned: " + address);
                    if (_scannedItems.ContainsKey(address))
                    {
                        var scannedItem = _scannedItems[address];
                        scannedItem.TextRSSIValue.text = rssi.ToString();
                        BluetoothLEHardwareInterface.Log("already in list " + rssi.ToString());

          if (rssi > -50 && address == "65F9196B-96FE-98E5-B971-1A8EBCEAB08D")
                        {
                            Debug.Log("Near beacon is " + name + "  " + rssi + "  :" + address);

                            ShowPrefab();


                        }

                        else if (rssi < -50)
                        {
                            Debug.Log("Far");
                            HidePrefab();

                        }


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        BluetoothLEHardwareInterface.Log("item new: " + address);
                        var newItem = Instantiate(ScannedItemPrefab);
                        if (newItem != null)
                        {
                            BluetoothLEHardwareInterface.Log("item created: " + address);
                            newItem.transform.parent = transform;

                            var scannedItem = newItem.GetComponent<ScannedItemScript>();
                            if (scannedItem != null)
                            {
                                BluetoothLEHardwareInterface.Log("item set: " + address);
                                scannedItem.TextAddressValue.text = address;
                                scannedItem.TextNameValue.text = name;
                                scannedItem.TextRSSIValue.text = rssi.ToString();

                                _scannedItems[address] = scannedItem;
                            }
                        }
                    }


            }, true);
```

Comment: Please ask only one question per Question.